# How can i get the value from a file using bash?

Tags: bash, file

I have file test.txt contains the following

```
AA=testing
BB=help
CC=hello
```

How can i make a bash script that will get each value and assign to a new variable?

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=testing
var2=help
var3=hello
```

thanks for the help

Comment: @EdMorton's answer on that duplicate question is the one I would choose (despite it not being the accepted answer).

Comment: How can i transfer the value from the file to the script?like above question?thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all `a = value` is not correct syntax in shell. In shell the spaces are important.

When you have a valid file, you can use the `eval` function to evaluate that file as a string, or simply `source` it.